# Mysql convert string to time

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

Currently, my `start_time` column was `string` type.

I want to convert `8:00 AM` to `8:00:00` using MySQL.
I have tried like this but it didn't work `SELECT STR_TO_DATE('8:00 AM', '%h:%i %p')`

Comment: Better to correct the mistake of putting times in a string column

Comment: It works fine when I try it:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dde2d3a7043471fa22c31fcbda8642ab.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Oddly it seems to fail on MySQL5.7

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? Is it MySQL or mariaDB?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Laravel, I recommend to use [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/).

Carbon is an inherited php class from DateTime what makes you able to format times in any way you want and like.

Related to your question:

`SELECT STR_TO_DATE("08:00 AM", "%h:%i %p"); // output: 08:00:00`

Works fine, so there is something else that causes your problem, but you are giving us not enough information to help you further.

- What db are you using?
- What version?
- what outpout do you get?

etc.

Comment: _Note_ Answers shouldn't really have questions in them